# Un-rar-ring a 34GB and 88GB file

Tags: windows, rar

We have received two RAR files, one that is 34GB, another that is 88GB, that we need to extract.

We have tried extracting them on Windows using 7-zip twice on two different computers and they have locked up as we try to unrar them.

Any suggestions on how to unrar such enormous files on Windows?  Use Linux, maybe?

Comment: I assume you have plenty of disk space when decompressing them? Its also possible the rar files are corrupt.

Comment: Extract the smaller one and walk away for the night and come back and check in the morning. It may just be consuming a ton of resources on the machine you're running the decompression process from and you just simply need to wait otherwise it gives the appearance that it is locked up on the machine. Kick it off before you leave for the night for the smaller file and then come back in the morning and see the progress, disk space consideration is indeed important as well since 34 GB compressed will likely be much larger when decompressed depending on various factors of course.